# Ошибка при сохранении строки в БД

Tags: java, android

Вот такой код сохраняет переменные в БД

```
cv.put(DateBase.KEY_IDME,editText.getText().toString());
cv.put(DateBase.KEY_TO,editText.getText().toString());
cv.put(DateBase.KEY_DATA,editText.getText().toString());
db.insert(DateBase.TABLE_CONTACTS,null,cv);
```

При вызове данных строк ошибка

```
Error inserting to=Name idme=Name data=Name android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "to": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO cont(to,idme,data) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

Comment: `to` является ключевым словом в SQLite. Его нужно брать в кавычки. А лучше вообще переименовать.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html ищите в пункт 110.